# Plot of function not showing up when called

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use the following code to plot the function `p_n` which is a function of N:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def factorial(N):
    fact = 1
    for num in range(2, N + 1):
        fact *= num
    return fact


a=1/(2**N)
b=factorial(N)
c=factorial(N-25)
d=factorial(25)

p_n=a*((b)/(c*d))

y = p_n
x = N
plt.title("Factorial Graph")
plt.xlabel("x axis")
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.plot(x, y, color="blue")
plt.show()
```

When I run this code, I just get a blank screen. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: `x` and `y` are just single numbers, i.e., they are not something like lists of numbers. If you try `plt.plot(x, y, color="blue", marker='o')` instead, you will see it just draws a point.

Comment: But p_n is a function of N. That is as N changes, so does the value of p_n. It wouldn't be just a single number. I want to plot how p_n changes as N changes.

Comment: No, it is a single number. In the code you provided `N` is not defined, so I assume you put `N = 10` for example. (Otherwise you would see an error). Then you do `x = N`, which is just a number. Did you put something else in `N`? Then you should have provided that in your code.

Comment: Put `print(x)` in your code right before `plot(...)` and check what you see.

Comment: Ok yeah it's only a single point. That's so weird. How can I plot it so p_n is a function of N, and get the plot of p_n as N varies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users have commented, x and y are single values as yo uhave defined them.

I would recommend defining `p_n` as a function, and using list comprehension or arrays for x and y. For example;

```
def p_n(N):
    a=1/(2**N)
    b=factorial(N)
    c=factorial(N-25)
    d=factorial(25)
    return a*((b)/(c*d))

N = 10
x = list(range(N))
y = [p_n(x_val) for x_val in x]
```

Then pass `x` and `y` to `plt.plot(...)` as you did before. You should get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!